# can't browse ASP.NET web app on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows, azure, iis

I can't browse my ASP.NET web app locally at the VM.
From VM > IIS Manager > Sites > virtual directory of my web > Browse I get: "This page can’t be displayed"
From local VM/localhost I get: "The webpage cannot be found".
I can, however, run the web app ok from Visual Studio in the same directory pointed to by the IIS virtual directory.

Last year, I could browse my web from Internet ok.
Then I de-allocated the VM (last year).
After re-allocation and restarting VM (this year), I can't browse the web app locally from the VM.

I can RDP to my VM ok and all my files and folders are still there.
Server Manager > IIS > shows my web app as "Online".

In my Azure > VM >dashboard:  I sawthat the Public Virtual IP (VIP) Address has changed.  So, I set DNS provider (Network Solutions) A Record to this new IP.

I created a new Visual Studio > File New > Web Site > ASP.NET Web Forms Site
and got this error:  Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer ("prayshep.cloudapp.net"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Management Service") is started.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE.)    Web_2017-03-16b     0

Comment: This sounds more of a Windows Server / IIS issue than Azure specific. Some configuration must have changed at some point... Did you try rebooting the VM first?

Comment: You mean restart Windows server.  Yes, several times.  Shutdown and re-start also.  But all I did was de-allocate last Nov'16.  I changed no config.  Then, a week ago I re-allocated, and restarted (from Azure dashboard).  VM works great, but can't browse virtual web.

Comment: Firstly, please try to restart (or stop and then start) web site from IIS, and then browse to your web page to check if same issue appear. Besides, please try to add a new WebSite under Sites node in IIS and check if you could browse to new site.

Comment: Restart did not fix. Adding again did not fix.  IIS > Add Website > Test Settings command got:  "cannot verify access to path" <physical path to web>

Comment: Do you try to ignore the warning message and add a new virtual directory? same issue "This page can’t be displayed" with new virtual directory?

Comment: yes, same issue.